# I'm Getting index error when using snscrape to scrape instagram

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

I'm trying to use snscrape to scrape instagram from Hashtag. Here's my code:

```
import snscrape.modules.instagram as sninstagram
import pandas as pd

query='google' 
ins_s=[]
limit=10
for ins in sninstagram.InstagramHashtagScraper(query).get_items():
     print(vars(ins))
     break
```

And I get this error: jsonData = r.text.split('window._sharedData = ')[1].split(';')[0] # May throw an IndexError if Instagram changes something again; we just let that bubble.
IndexError: list index out of range

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

this issue is due to changes on Instagram's side. They recently overhauled their site a bit. The snscraper library has not yet been modified to adapt to the changes at the time of writing. You can track the issue here: https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape/issues/520